# запуск сервера на node js по нажатию на ссылку

Tags: php, node.js

каким образом  можно запустить сервер node если на странице сделать кнопку или по нажатию на dom элемент

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В php есть [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php), можно с помощью него процесс запустить:

```
exec("node /path/to/my/script/myscript.js &", $output);
```

Comment: а что означает знак & и $output?

Comment: `&` указывает, чтобы скрипт продолжал работать и после завершения работы php скрипта. В переменную `$output` вывод node скрипта запишется.